# Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher\InvokedCount' not found' in phpUNIT 9 version

Tags: phpunit

Failed asserting that exception message 'Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher\InvokedCount' not found' contains.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure it out solution in multiple places. Couldn't found proper solution to this. Posting answer to make our dev's life easier.
PHP unit 9 version don't have InvokedCount.php under Matcher directory. It is actually replaced under Rule directory.
So if you face any issues , Do please replace Matcher with Rule

Example :

```
public function finalizeAssertions() {

$expectedNumberOfExecutions = new \PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher\InvokedCount(
                count($calls)
            );
}
```

Replace with :

```
public function finalizeAssertions() {
    
    $expectedNumberOfExecutions = new \PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Rule\InvokedCount(
                    count($calls)
                );
    }
```